# HTML + Jquery : Table + add / remove row buttons : pb with bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a simple table + add rows button. Into each new , I create a remove button.
My problem is that I cannot bind the 'click' event for the class 'remove'. Here is the simplified code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').bind('click', function () {
            $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>'+
                                 '</td><td>'+
                                 '<button type="button" class="remove">DEL</button>'+
                                 '</td></tr>');
        });
        $('.remove').bind('click', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the HTML code :

```
<html>
    <button class="" type="button" id="btnAdd">+</button>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Something
            </th>
            <th>
                Buttons
            </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I create a line into the HTML code, the **('.remove').bind** works but it doesn't work if the line is created with the **.append** method.

I tried to use **.on()** instead of .bind and the result is the same. I replaced the .bind with **.live** and it works but .live is deprecated.

For the moment, because I need to continue, I placed the $('.remove').bind(...); instruction just after the .append instruction. So each time I insert a new line, I bind. It works but it appears to me as a wrong method (because I bind a class and not an Id).

Can someone lights my candle ? Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your `.remove`. button is appended after the DOM has been loaded so you need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Also note the use of `on` over `bind` and `closest` instead of chained `parent` selectors for better maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a bind directly on the element when it is created, something like this:

```
$(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').bind('click', function () {
            var newRow = '<tr><td>'+
                                 '</td><td>'+
                                 '<button type="button" class="remove">DEL</button>'+
                                 '</td></tr>';                    

            function handler() { alert('DEL pressed!'); }

            $('#myTable').append(function() {
                      return $(newRow).click(handler);
                })

        });
});
```

Hope it helps.